# WebView Go Back Button inside Fragment

Tags: java, android

Inside a fragment, I'm using **WebView**. I simply query 2 options when **Back Button Clicked**

**First if;** url.equals("www.google.com") *[which works perfectly]*

**Second if;** !url.equals("www.google.com") *[doesn't work]*

I worked in debug mode, but my second if doesn't work, even though url is different than "google.com" and closes the app!

**Fragment.Java**

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (getView() == null) {
        return;
    }

    getView().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    getView().requestFocus();

    getView().setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

                if(url.equals("https://www.google.com")){

                    //normal geri

                    final AlertDialog.Builder builder_question1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
                    builder_question1.setTitle("Are you sure to close the app?");
                    builder_question1.setCancelable(true);
                    //POSITIVE BUTTON
                    builder_question1.setPositiveButton("yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            System.exit(0);

                        }
                    });

                    //NEGATIVE BUTTON
                    builder_question1.setNegativeButton("no",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            //do something...
                            //and dismiss
                            dialogInterface.dismiss();
                        }
                    });


                    builder_question1.create().show();



                }

                if(!url.equals("https://www.google.com")){
                   if(webView.canGoBack()){
                       webView.goBack();
                   }

                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    });



}
```

**WebViewClient**

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), ""+url, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, request);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {


            super.onLoadResource(view, url);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
           // Toast.makeText(getContext(), "page loaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        }

    });
    webView.loadUrl(url);
```

Comment: where are you setting variable `url` ?

Comment: Because it comes from webviewclient which is current url.

Answer (score 0):

Apply Back button in activity containing fragment

Comment: I tried, but more trouble came up. I actually query this back button for one of many tab fragments.

Answer (score 0):

it's one of an issue, the application gets crash for a second time because of wrong context type in dialog builder when you try to display the dialog.

Change the AlertDialog context from `getContext()` to `getActivity();` and `System.exit(0);` with `getActivity().finish();`

```
 final AlertDialog.Builder builder_question1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                        builder_question1.setTitle("Are you sure to close the app?");
                        builder_question1.setCancelable(true);
                        //POSITIVE BUTTON
                        builder_question1.setPositiveButton("yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                getActivity().finish();

                            }
                        });


if(!url.equals("https://www.google.com")){
                   if(webView.canGoBack()){
                       webView.goBack();
return false;
                   }

                }
```

Comment: Thanks but as I said, first "if" is working well. It's something wrong with second "if" which is in the below.

Comment: @juniordev i have updated the answer,return false so it overwrite default behaviour of event

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this helps you

```
if(url.equals("https://www.google.com")){
     //normal geri
} else {
    if(webView.canGoBack()){
       webView.goBack();
    }
}
```

Comment: I also tried this before, didn't work. I think its something wrong with return types.

Comment: Do yo try log before `webView.canGoBack()`?

Comment: Yes, as I said it doesn't go into 'else'. I also tried "if" instead of "else". That didnt work, too.